# Protect an electronic transaction from changes by one of participants of this transaction

Tags: security, e-commerce

I need to develop a system which allows users to invest their money to some project. The system accumulates money of all investors in my bank account. The main requirement is to protect both sides of deal (investors and me) from machinations.
Lets say, Alice invested 1000$ to some project. Then I decided to change 1000$ to 900$. In this case Alice must have a possibility to go to curt and win it.

My current idea is to send Alice a specific file (some electronic document) which contains an info about deal between Alice and me including an info about 1000$.
On the other side, Alice also can change amount from 1000$ to 1100$ in this file. And I also must be protected. So, how could this be implemented?

Also I don't want to use Blockchain implementation and looking for alternative.

Could you guide me in this theme?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use blockchain, then the only solution is a trusted third party. Well, you simply need to trust someone or something to make the whole not deniable. And having things stand up in court is even more complex than that. Contact a lawyer regarding this one.

But let's try to make a draft of how this all could play out. Let's say you have two parties: Alice and Bob. Bob wants to make Alice an offer to do some job and pay her 1000$ afterwards. Alice likes this offer and signs it with her own private key. She sends the contract signed with her key to Bob. Bob signs it with his own key and sends the contract back to Alice. Does not work much different, that real contracts in real life, does it? Now Alice does her job and requests payment. What can go wrong?

Well, Bob may try to deny that he did the offer in the first place and claim it was someone else. How do you prove that Bob made the offer? You need a third party to confirm that the key did belong to Bob and that it was not blacklisted in the time it was used for the signature.

This is one of many scenarios how to play that out. And it does not even scratch the surface of checking if Bob was capable of making and informed and conscious decision of crating an offer (binding transaction) in the first place.

This smells like a brilliant problem to solve. Have fun playing with it.